# Is there a term for a horizontal moon crescent

Tags: the-moon, terminology

I seen the other day the moon lit directly below or towards my horizon perfectly.

My question, is there a term for when a moon's crescent is aligned with the viewer's horizon?

Comment: Maybe there are colloquial terms, but no astronomer I've met has used terms beyond 'waxing/waning crescent'.

Answer (score 3):

No formal astronomical term, but it is sometimes said to be "on its back"

Examples from "[weather lore](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nR1EBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=hang%20your%20hat%20on%20the%20moon%27s%20horns&source=bl&ots=7ii8Gs9yVv&sig=UpM23Wj0JdbrNaF_vXPgs4LCBHg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIj-XyjMHWAhUoKsAKHQ_YAAkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=hang%20your%20hat%20on%20the%20moon's%20horns&f=false)"

> When the moon lies on its back
>   Then the sou-west wind will crack.
>
> When the moon is on its back,
>   She sucks the wet into her lap.
>
> It's sure to be a dry moon if it lies on its back
>   so you can hang your hat on its horns.